# How to filter products by language in prestahop orders

Tags: filter, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

We have one product (physical not prestashop product) that has 3 different packages.

When we are printing the invoices we want to be able to distinguish which package should we send him.

We can distinguish which product we have to sell by which language the user used.

Right now we see no way of doing this.

When we go to the orders section, there is no way of filtering by language.

We thought about doing three different products but that would mean that we would have to show different products for different languages, that doesn't seem to possible either.

Please note that adding an attribute would kind of work, in this particular case, this is the packaging we're talking about (specifically the language), so making the user choose that doesn't make a lot of sense for us usability wise.

We are just at the start of configuring the store so we wouldn't mind any setup that would allow this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered adding "language" attribute to your product? This way you would have only one product and the users would be able to select the language that he wants instead of you determining the language by interface/account.

You could also keep track of quantities for different languages and the selected language would be visible throughout the checkout and the back-office.

EDIT:

As I understand you would like to detect the interface language the customer used while made the purchase; Field `id_lang` is actually saved which each order (a column exists in the database table). I tested it and it actually corresponds with the interface language of the user.

Therefore, all the information is there. What you'd need to do is get/write a simple module which would display this languge in order details page. Adding an actual column in the order list is possible but it would be much more difficult;

Comment: Thanks for that, I should have clarified in my question that that is one of the things we considered, it kind of solves the problem but I really don' like that the user has to chose it, IMO the interface for that looks very bad, specially usability wise, I don't want to put that burden to the user. I apologize I didn't clarify this before.